# Django allauth emailverification

Tags: django, smtp, django-allauth, ionos

I use allauth and want to send a verfication email.

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.ionos.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'info@mydomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'secretpassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

I use Ionos, the error which shown in browser:

```
SMTPAuthenticationError at /accounts/signup/
(535, b'Authentication credentials invalid')
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/
Django Version: 4.0.1
Exception Type: SMTPAuthenticationError
Exception Value:    
(535, b'Authentication credentials invalid')
```

The credentials are correct, maybe there's an error with the passwordencoding, or I'm doing it completly wrong.
Do I need any smtp client in the django backend?

Comment: `The credentials are correct`: Well, the server doesn't agree with you. Try using port `465` and if that doesn't work either consider opening a support ticket with Ionos.

Comment: thanks. No I've connection unexpectedly closed.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the port and TLS so SSL now it's working

```
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.ionos.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'info@mydomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'secretpassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
```